# Template template argument access

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11, generics

Lets say I have two classes. First one is simple template class `Point<N, T>` and the other one is `Function<Point<N, T>>`. Is it possible to access in class Function to type `T` and int `N`.

Here is my `Point` which I think it's OK

```
template<int N, class T>
class Point {
public:
    Point() {
        std::fill(std::begin(data), std::end(data), T(0));
    }

    Point(const std::initializer_list<T> &init) {
        std::copy(init.begin(), init.end(), std::begin(data));
    }

public: // just for easier testing, otherwise protected/private
    T data[N];
};
```

and now the `Function` implementation that I think has some issues

```
template<template<int, typename> class P, int N, typename T>
class Function {
public:
    T operator()(const P<N, T> &pt) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            // do something and expect loop unrolling
        }
        return T(0); // for example's sake
    }

    T operator()(const P<N, T> &pt1, const P<N, T> &pt2) {
        // force pt1 and pt2 to have the same `N` and `T`
        return T(0); // for example's sake
    }
};
```

And here is how I imagine I'd use my classes. Maybe I'm thinking too much java-like :)

```
typedef Point<3, float> Point3f;
typedef Point<4, float> Point4f;

Point3f pt3f({ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });       // Point<3, float>
Point4f pt4f({ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 });  // Point<4, float>

Function<Point3f> f3;         // Function<Point<3, float>> f3;

float val = f3(pt3f);         // no error
float val = f3(pt3f, pt3f);   // no error
float val = f3(pt4f);         // compile error
float val = f3(pt4f, pt3f);   // compile error
```

How can I achieve such behaviour? I keep getting errors like `"Point<3, float>" is not a class template` or `too few arguments for class template "Function"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class Point>
class Function;

template<template<int, typename> class P, int N, typename T>
class Function<P<N,T>>
```

to replace:

```
template<template<int, typename> class P, int N, typename T>
class Function
```

solves your syntax problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works now. I was affraid this was not possible.